# Normal to the Hypersurfaces

Tags: general-relativity, action, boundary-conditions

I am trying to understand the derivation of the [Hilbert-Einstein action](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93Hilbert_action). However it requires a knowledge about hyper-surfaces for the boundaries of the integrals and also about the normal to the hyper-surface $n^{a}$ for the derivations.

Could anyone refer me to a good source or try explain to me the normal to the hyper-surface and also why $n^{a}n^{b}n^{c}$ = 0?

In the derivation it says that:

If we define $g^{ab}$ as $h^{ab}+t n^{a}n^{b}$, where $t=n_a n^a$ then

$n^{c}(h^{ab}+t n^{a}n^{b})({\partial}_{c}{\delta g}_{ab}-{\partial}_{a}{\delta g}_{cb})=-n^{c}h^{ab}{\partial}_{a}{\delta g}_{cb}$ on hypersurface.

See [page 31 on this manuscript](http://www.if.nu.ac.th/sites/default/files/bin/BS_chakkrit.pdf) for the derivation

Comment: The equation $n^a n^b n^c = 0$ is definitely false. It can only be true if $n^a = 0.$ Maybe you mean $\epsilon_{abcd} n^a n^b n^c = 0$ which is true, but for trivial reasons.

Comment: I don't know if this is useful, but Hilbert's original paper (not translated, sorry) can be found at http://users.physik.fu-berlin.de/~kleinert/files/hilbert1905.pdf.

Comment: If we define $g^{ab}$ as $h^{ab}+t n^{a}n^{b}$, where $t=n_a n^a$ then

$n^{a}(h^{ab}+t n^{a}n^{b})({\partial}_{c}{\delta g}_{ab}-{\partial}_{a}{\delta g}_{cb})=-n^{c}h^{ab}{\partial}_{a}{\delta g}_{cb}$ on hypersurface.

Comment: $n^a \to n^c$ at the very beginning of your last equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not proving

$$n^a n^b n^c =0 $$

But in proving

$$n^a n^b n^c (\partial_{c}\delta g_{ab} - \partial_{a}\delta g_{cb}) = 0$$

Observe the parenthetic term, we will write it as

$$f_{abc} = (\partial_{c}\delta g_{ab} - \partial_{a}\delta g_{cb})$$

Then observe

$$ f_{abc} = -f_{cba}$$

We get the result immediately, because index gymnastics gives us:

$$n^b (n^an^c f_{abc}) = 0$$

Comment: may you should see http://www.if.nu.ac.th/sites/default/files/bin/BS_chakkrit.pdf (page 31) for the derivation

Comment: @user38032, that's definitely a typo or (worse) a serious error in the manuscript. If $n^a n^b n^c =0$ then $n^a = 0$, and you have serious problems in that situation...you probably should consult http://www.physics.uoguelph.ca/poisson/research/agr.pdf (pg 95) for the variation of the boundary term...and pg 121 for the Hamiltonian version of the action...

Comment: It can't be a mistake because there is another manuscript that uses the same derivation and it has actually been published, see http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10714-010-1012-6, page 4.

Comment: OH! What the first publication lacked, that the second had, was that you are evaluating this on the boundary to a region. This is all explained in detail in the paper I linked to (pdf page 111), or Poisson's book based on it...